# WPF Application runs in VS, but doesn't run when published. Awesomium

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

I'm working on a browser and I am using awesomium as my html ui engine. The browser builds fine in Visual Studios, but when ever I publish it and try to install it or have a friend try to install it, It installs, then does nothing.

I have went into Event Viewer and found the error it was throwing.

http://pastebin.com/QRaZqh71

Its to long to do proper formatting here.

and a second error(this just looks like details)

```
Faulting application name: Browser.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x53aca5ff
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17055, time stamp: 0x532943a3
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00011d4d
Faulting process id: 0x21e0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf9193251760ed
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GEVJE39E.P71\73WXDRQC.4RL\telb..tion_8ece489c77ef3966_0001.0000_4d8e466853b7f19a\Browser.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 62e5b4c0-fd86-11e3-bfcb-08606e448d63
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I followed the insturctions on the awesomium wiki on how properly redistribute with my application, and that fixed the initial problem of my friends computer not having awesomium, but not this one.

Comment: did you set your project to 'x86' instead of 'any cpu'?

Comment: Always the same answer... add some sort of logging to your application, so that you can work out what is going on in the deployed application.